# Empty space at the bottom of UITableView after adding UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm making a UITableView that displays a record of past events. It all looked great until I added a search bar at the top. It all looks how I want when it's scrolled to the top:

[image]

However, when I scroll to the bottom there's now a bunch of white space. It's hard to tell in this screenshot as there's no screen border but the tableview scroll will rest on this screen with about half the page blank:

[image]

Interestingly, when I activate the search bar at all (i.e. click in it and then press cancel) the white space goes away until this view appears again.

I've tried all sorts of settings for the tableView as well as using reloadData() at various stages of the view layout process to no avail. I know the number of rows is correct. The only thing I've found to make the white space go away is to disable the search bar. But I want the search bar!

Here's the code for the search bar:

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by keyword, name, etc."
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 224/256, green: 244/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 1)
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.pastServicesTable.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

Comment: Hi, why don't you try giving color to tableview, table cell to know what that white spce exactly is

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. Stating the the tableview row height in the viewDidLoad (ie. self.tableView.rowHeight = 350) fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly! Do you have any idea why this works? My rowHeights are different depending on the cell and I set tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension in ViewWillAppear. Also with your solution it seems that if I set tableView.rowHeight below around 100 then there's still space at the bottom (more space the closer rowHeight is to 0) but I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

I solved extra bottom space this way (in viewDidLoad):

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200 // should be more than real row height will be
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are observing `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` & `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and changing the `contentInset` of the tableView (adding keyBoard size height to contentInsets) and not setting the contentInsets to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`when keyboard hides.

Comment: Hi, nope I'm not observing either notification or changing the contentinset (at least not in the code or the attributes inspector from what I can tell). The only time the keyboard comes up is when using the search bar. Also the height of the white space at the bottom seems to vary erratically from about a quarter to three quarters of the screen's height.